# Redmine Digest version 2.2.2.stable

Tags: redmine, digest

I have installed https://github.com/drewkeller/redmine_digest plugin but for the life of me cant set up a cron to run it daily .

Can anyone help a poor boy out ?

```
root@ip-10-202-39-172:/home/bitnami/apps/redmine/htdocs/bin# rake redmine:send_digest start=1 days=1 project=myproject Rails.env="productio" --trace
(in /opt/bitnami/apps/redmine/htdocs)
** Invoke redmine:send_digest (first_time)
** Execute redmine:send_digest
rake aborted!
string not matched
/opt/bitnami/apps/redmine/htdocs/plugins/redmine_digest/lib/tasks/digest.rake:47:in `[]='
/opt/bitnami/apps/redmine/htdocs/plugins/redmine_digest/lib/tasks/digest.rake:47:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => redmine:send_digest
root@ip-10-202-39-172:/home/bitnami/apps/redmine/htdocs/bin#



root@ip-10-202-39-172:/home/bitnami/apps/redmine/htdocs/bin# rake redmine:send_digest start=1 days=1 project=SSO Rails.env="productio" --trace
(in /opt/bitnami/apps/redmine/htdocs)
** Invoke redmine:send_digest (first_time)
** Execute redmine:send_digest
rake aborted!
string not matched
/opt/bitnami/apps/redmine/htdocs/plugins/redmine_digest/lib/tasks/digest.rake:47:in `[]='
/opt/bitnami/apps/redmine/htdocs/plugins/redmine_digest/lib/tasks/digest.rake:47:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/opt/bitnami/ruby/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => redmine:send_digest
root@ip-10-202-39-172:/home/bitnami/apps/redmine/htdocs/bin#
```

Redmine 2.2.2.stable

Default administrator account changed
Attachments directory writable
Plugin assets directory writable
RMagick available (optional)

```
Environment:
  Redmine version                          2.2.2.stable
  Ruby version                             1.9.3 (x86_64-linux)
  Rails version                            3.2.11
  Environment                              production
  Database adapter                         Mysql2
Redmine plugins:
  openid_fix                               0.1.0
  redmine_digest                           0.2.0
  redmine_googlesss                        0.0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Some other people have reported issues with line 47 in the rake.digest file. You could try the same workaround: https://github.com/drewkeller/redmine_digest/issues/29

Also see https://github.com/drewkeller/redmine_digest/issues/36. Looks like you crossposted your question.